# Liquibase with Spring Boot fails the whole application if it has failed changeset precondition with onFail==MARK_RAN/CONTINUE/etc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, liquibase

Briefly: if precodition of changeset fails and there is **onFail** property != "WARN" - i got

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase'
```

---

I have a gradle project with

- liquibase gradle plugin `ver. 2.2.1`
- `implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.25.0'`

i have a changelog-master like

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: .\db\changelog\changelogs\db.changelog-init.yaml
```

and db.changelog-init.yaml:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - preConditions:
    - onFail: MARK_RAN
    - changeLogPropertyDefined:
      - property: profile
      - value: prod, stage
  - include:
      file: .\db\changelog\changelogs\changesets\sql\init-structure.sql
  - include:
      file: .\db\changelog\changelogs\changesets\sql\init-populate.sql
```

profile property passes to liquibase properties in my application.properties like

```
spring.liquibase.parameters.profile=${spring.profiles.active}
```

and, obviously, i have this

```
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
```

everything else is done by spring boot.

i set a profile property to **dev**, so preconditions should fail.

if i delete preconditions from my init-changelog, or change MARK_RAN to WARN (strictly), everything works fine - i have my changesets applied to my database (so, this is correct)
if i set profile property to prod/stage - everything OK

but if there will be onFail == WARN/CONTINUE/MARK_RAN etc, it fails **at spring level** with

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]:
> liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException:
> liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
> 1 preconditions failed
> Preconditions Failed
> db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml : Expected changelog property 'profile' to have a value of 'prod, stage'.  Got 'dev'

and application fails completely!

i coould not get, what is wrong, cuz everything seems fine...

full errorStack:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]:
> liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException:
> liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
> 1 preconditions failed
> Preconditions Failed
> db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml : Expected changelog property 'profile' to have a value of 'prod, stage'.  Got 'dev'
>
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1173)
> ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:936)
> ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
> ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
> ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753)
> ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455)
> ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)
> ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342)
> ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331)
> ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]    at
> vk.atlas.contractors.ContractorsBackendApplication.main(ContractorsBackendApplication.java:27)
> ~[main/:na] Caused by:
> liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException:
> liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException:
> liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
> 1 preconditions failed
> Preconditions Failed
> db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml : Expected changelog property 'profile' to have a value of 'prod, stage'.  Got 'dev'
>
> at
> liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:303)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1822)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771)
> ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]   ... 18 common frames omitted Caused
> by: liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException:
> liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
> 1 preconditions failed
> Preconditions Failed
> db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml : Expected changelog property 'profile' to have a value of 'prod, stage'.  Got 'dev'
>
> at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:237)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$0(Liquibase.java:242)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:184)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:193) ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:183)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:162) ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]
> at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:1403)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:231)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:209)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:342)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(SpringLiquibase.java:293)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:184)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:193) ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:183)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:162) ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:250)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:286)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   ... 20 common frames omitted Caused
> by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
> 1 preconditions failed
> Preconditions Failed
> db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml : Expected changelog property 'profile' to have a value of 'prod, stage'.  Got 'dev'
>
> at
> liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:353)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.command.core.helpers.DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.run(DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.java:92)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   at
> liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:214)
> ~[liquibase-core-4.25.0.jar:na]   ... 36 common frames omitted

Comment: It's not a failure at the Spring level. It's Liquibase that's throwing an exception as the preconditions haven't been met. The exception's being thrown because Liquibase "expected changelog property 'profile' to have a value of 'prod, stage'". Instead it got 'dev'.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson yes, it is. but there is onFail property that says what to do when it fails, isn't it? and it is HALT by default that says to just stop, not to fail the application. 
and if i set it to CONTINUE - it should continue running changesets instead of failing, shouldn't it?

Comment: That's still a Liquibase problem. It is throwing an exception when the database update is performed. If it has been configured in such a way that the update should be considered successful and the application should continue to start up despite the problems encountered, it should not throw an exception.